# mysql_insert_id with update

Tags: php, mysql

After executing the query below I use the PHP function `mysql_insert_id()` and it always gives me 0.

```
UPDATE 
    tbl_training_types 
SET 
    fld_serial = $serial_no, 
    fld_name = $training_name, 
    fld_description = $training_description 
WHERE 
    fld_id = $id
```

Comment: Well, you're running an `UPDATE`, not an `INSERT`, so that's to be expected. But don't you have `$id` right there already? Why do you need to look it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update a note in database you already have something using what you can identify it. In your example you already have `$id` which should be containing the value of data you have recently updated. If you don't have `id` and you try to update with name or something different after update you can simply retrieve updated data with simple query:

```
select * from table_name where your condition
```

**Note:** `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and won't be supported in future versions. You should be using either [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score -1):

Return Values

The ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query on success, 0 if the previous query does not generate an AUTO_INCREMENT value, or FALSE if no MySQL connection was established.

Source [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)