# Retrieve last updated timestamp in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have the following query:

```
UPDATE myTable SET myTime=utc_timestamp() WHERE myID=something
```

I would like to retrieve the timestamp that was set, preferably within the same query of with something like mysql_insert_id().

Thank you all !

Comment: how about instead of using the db's time function you parse the current time (`time()`) to it from php, then you have it in php and the db

Comment: Yes, that would indeed be a good way to do it. Just wonder why I didn't think of it ! I'm just used to use utc_timestamp() I guess... But nonetheless, I think the question remains if you had a table with ON UPDATE CURERNT_TIMESTAMP, how would you retrieve the new timestamp following an update ? Is doing a select the only way ?

Comment: yes, doing a select is the only way

Comment: Now that I think of it, getting the time() from the PHP server would require it to be perfectly in sync with the MySQL server which is a bit risky I think... That's why a usually stick to DB time... I guess I'll have to select it then... But in this case, I see a potential problem : how can I be sure that this is done atomically ?

Answer (score -1):

First, mysql_insert_id() is doing a new query. Why you want the data returned you currently saved? Then you might be able to access via the Datacontainer/Variable you got it from.

mysql_insert_id() is just returning the last inserted id of a table. Its not delivering any more data.

To really answer your question, you should tell what you want to do first.

IMPORTANT: mysql_**insert**_id() wont return you the id of an updated row !

In case you want to get the last inserted id of an updated row - take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14002784/3048505

Comment: Euh... I totally understand what mysql_insert_id is and what it does. What I need to know is the timestamp that was updated. I have no way of knowking it beforehand. So I was wondering if there was something **like** msql_insert_id that would tell me what timestamp was used in the last update... Or if there as a way to return the timestamp used **within** the same query. I think this is a legitimate question that should not be voted down...

Comment: No this is not possible within the same Query. You'll have to query the Row with the ID you updated. I have no reputation to vote this question down - not me!

You will either have to use the Timestamp retrieved in PHP (time()) or put another select-query onto your table.