# How to update record id?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have to update multiple records.

I call this method to update multiple records.

How to update all unique_id records in one query?

```
public function updateLease($data)
{
    $sql = "UPDATE tbl_lease SET company = '".$data['company']."', total_price = '".$data['total_price_paid']."', price_per_hecters = '".$data['price_per_hactare']."' WHERE record_date = '".$data['record_date']."' AND lease_code = '".$data['lease_code']."' AND region = '".$data['region']."' AND site_id = '".$data['site_id']."'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if ($result) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_insert\_id with update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002763/mysql-insert-id-with-update)

Comment: don't use mysql_ * functions now.. 
Check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: please relate to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388025/how-to-get-id-of-the-last-updated-row-in-mysql

Comment: Interesting trick @webcrazymaniac

Comment: I'm sure it is, but I never had to use it :)